# Joomla: How to display an article in its own page rather than in home page?

Tags: php, joomla

For example, my joomla website is www.abc.com.

When I first entered, everything works fine. The link of an article was www.abc.com/index.php/component/content/article/144-2010-11-16-08-35-52, and it linked to another page.

But after I clicked "Home" on the navigation bar, whose url is http://www.abc.com/index.php/home, the link of that article changed into www.abc.com/index.php/home/144-2010-11-16-08-35-52. When I clicked that link, the content of the article simply showed on the home page.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Global Configuration make sure that the SEO settings has the (Use Apache mod_rewrite) is set to on and rename the htaccess.txt file on the root of your installation to .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Point an unpublished menu item to the article and use the link or alias as the page.